# How to update softwares in a company

Tags: development-process, programmer-relations, protocols

If a company wants to update their systems like for example ERP or CRM or a bookkeeping system etc. How can they best do this.. Just update the systems on every computer and hoping it works 100%? Or test it on 1 computer?

Are there best practises for this? Or even how is this called in the IT world? Is it ITIL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect a release management cycle based on [DTAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development,_testing,_acceptance_and_production).

Users should try the new versions in an acceptance environment and then maybe start upgrading only a couple of users in production to find major issues not found in acceptance.